# Avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when serializing to Json?

Tags: java, json, serialization, concurrency

We have a class `Document` which uses a private member of type `Map<String, Object>` as storage. Objects of this type are kept in memory and are (very frequently) modified by (potentially) multiple threads. It also happens that these objects (or, specifically the underlying Maps) are serialized out over HTTP on request. The serialization format is Json, and the library in use is currently Google's `Gson`

When serialization occurs simultaneously as a modification that introduces a new `Map.Entry` we see `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`. This makes a lot of sense intuitively, since Gson is probably iterating over the `entrySet` which is being modified.

How can we avoid this? Do we need to resort to always passing a deep copy of the Map to Gson? In that case, how would you implement said deep copy, given that the map can contain all Json primitives, including `List` and `Map`?

Comment: how are you controlling the thread-safety of this Map in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I question the wisdom of serializing an object that is being updated so often, using a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) should at least alleviate your concurrency issues.